# php object oriented calculator

Tags: php, function, class

Hello im trying to make an object as learning task which takes a number and calculate it three times and echos every step.

```
<?

// neues Objekt der Klasse erzeugen
$stringManager = new StringManager();

// output String initialisieren
$meinString = "";
$zahl = "100";
$stringManager->setMeinString($meinString);
$stringManager->setZahl($zahl);

// Schritte ausführen
for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++) {
  $stringManager->machSchritt($i,$zahl);
}

// String ausgeben
echo $stringManager->getMeinString();

// Klasse StringManager
class StringManager {
  var $meinString;
  var $zahl;

  function StringManager() {
  }

  function machSchritt($welchenSchritt,$zahl) {
    switch ($welchenSchritt) {
      case 1:
        $zahl + 50;
        break;
      case 2:
        $zahl / 2;
        break;
      case 3:
        $zahl * 5;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    $this->append("schritt".$welchenSchritt." fertig...");
    $this->append("Zahl:".$zahl." ");
  }

  function append($what) {
    $this->meinString .= $what;
  }
  //function append($what) {
    //$this->zahl .= $what;
  //}
  function setMeinString($value) {
    $this->meinString = $value;
  }

  function getMeinString() {
    return $this->meinString;
  }

  function setZahl($value) {
    $this->zahl = $value;
  }

  function getZahl() {
    return $this->zahl;
  }
}

?>
```

My output is: "schritt1 fertig...Zahl:100 schritt2 fertig...Zahl:100 schritt3 fertig...Zahl:100"

But I expect it to be "schritt1 fertig...Zahl:150 schritt2 fertig...Zahl:75 schritt3 fertig...Zahl:375

Please help me find what im doing wrong.

Comment: First you could use english since this is the language of this forum. You set `100` as tring. Probably try it without `"` so its a number. Check your `switch-case`: if the number always stays `100` it's because none of the case matched -> default -> nothing is done. Try to print out `$welchenschritt` to see if it comes correctly. And within the case try to print out something like `case 1` to see if they are called correctly.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is between this lines:

```
    $zahl + 50;
    break;
  case 2:
    $zahl / 2;
    break;
  case 3:
    $zahl * 5;
```

if you want to increase/manipulate the variable `$zahl` so you have to use it:

```
    $zahl += 50;
    break;
  case 2:
    $zahl /= 2;
    break;
  case 3:
    $zahl *= 5;
```

btw: your code is deprecated.

```
class StringManager {
  var $meinString;
  var $zahl;

  function StringManager() {
  }
}
```

should replace with

```
class StringManager {
  private $meinString;
  private $zahl;

  public function __construct() {
  }
}
```

**update:**

ah, now i understand, you need to work with your value.
so use this instead:

```
    $this->zahl += 50;
    break;
  case 2:
    $this->zahl /= 2;
    break;
  case 3:
    $this->zahl *= 5;

$this->append("Zahl:".$this->zahl." ");
```

But it would be better, to use your setter (with typecasting) and getter methods.

**warning**
your code looks like php4 code. php4 is not supported since 2008 (http://php.net/eol.php).

Comment: I need to use the deprecated code, I got this as a task. But I dont really understand it

Comment: Ok I did your "+=" solution, but now the code gives me the numbers "150" "50" and "500" but I would like to first add the 50 then use the new result and then do it /2 so 150 / 2 then use the new result again

Comment: Ok great, now it uses the result for the next step, but it does not use the 100 it starts at 0 not at 100, it is now 50, 25, 125, this is so weird